# reading linux inode bitmap

Tags: c++, c, linux, inode, superblock

I'm going to fetch linux inode bitmaps with c++. I've use this code to fetch super block first:

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <linux/ext2_fs.h>
    #include <linux/fs.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <linux/fs.h>

    using namespace std;

    /*
     * 
     */

    int main() {
        int fd;
        char boot[1024];
        struct ext2_super_block super_block;

        fd = open("/dev/sda1", O_RDONLY);
    /* Reads the boot section and the superblock */
    read(fd, boot, 1024);
    read(fd, &super_block, sizeof (struct ext2_super_block));

    /* Prints the Magic Number */
    printf("%x\n", super_block.s_magic);

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

but every time i run it , i get a error :

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h:181:18: error: ‘S_ISDIR’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h:183:23: error: ‘S_ISREG’ was not declared in this scope
```

I couldn't find any good example or tutorial for this.is there anybody to help me?

EDIT :
I've include `<linux/stat.h>` but still get same error.

Comment: You can't read *linux inode table*: there's no such things since each filesystem have it's own format (ext2,3,4 / reiserfs / xfs / btrfs / etc.)

Comment: BTW, to read a ext2, ext3 or ext4 you might want to use functions provided by *libext2fs* from *e2fsprogs* package.

Comment: whould you help me to use this package?

Comment: you could have a look at https://github.com/mandriva-management-console/pulse-imaging-client/blob/master/tools/revosave/image_e2fs.c

Answer (score 3):

```
#grep -rw S_ISREG /usr/src/linux/include
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/fs.h:  if (S_ISREG(inode->i_mode) || S_ISDIR(inode->i_mode) ||
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/fs.h.~1~:  if (S_ISREG(inode->i_mode) || S_ISDIR(inode->i_mode) ||
/usr/src/linux/include/linux/stat.h:#define S_ISREG(m)  (((m) & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG)
```

So you should find stat.h in yours kernel source tree and include it.

Comment: how can i use this...would you help me?i've include <stat.h> in my project but still get errors

Comment: <linux/stat.h> will only work if you pass `-I/path/to/your/linux/kernel/sources` to your compiler

Comment: shoul I include it in my project or in ext2_fs.h file?

Comment: I include it both in main project and ext2_fs.h file but still get the same error

Answer (score 2):

The Linux source code "stat.h" is not the same file as  that comes with the C-library. They just happen to have the same name. You will need to set your include path to find the correct stat.h (you may need BOTH, depending on what you are trying to do).

Comment: would you give me some source sample to read superblock and inode bitmaps?